# The App ID 'xxxx' appears to be in use by the App Store, so it can not be removed at this time

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-developer

I have been using my own personal Apple account to test creating test provisional profiles etc a new ios app. I know have a proper work account we need to use for the app.

I tried to add this to the work account and it said the app id is already in use.

So I now want to delete it from my own account, but I just get "The App ID 'xxx' appears to be in use by the App Store, so it cannot be removed at this time".

The app has been nowhere near the app store, and it's not even set up correctly, so I just want to completely remove it from this account and add it to the other proper. I have deleted all the provisional profiles, is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Create an application in iTunesConnect and then transfer the app to your new account.

Comment: If I go into iTunes Connect, I don't have the ability to either delete (my preference) or to transfer it. According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) I should have access to the delete/transfer buttons if the status is `Prepare for Submission` which mine is (it has never been in the store - it was only put here as start of me learning what to do) All I can see under the Additional Information is *View on App Store*

Comment: One of the conditions  to be eligible for app transfer is that *The app has at least one approved version*. Similarly, for deleting *You can delete your app if there is at least one approved version of the app*.  So, probably the only solution you have is to use a different bundle id.  You could try a support request to see if Apple can delete your app

Comment: Hmm, that is crazy! Why would you have to have something you don't want approved before deleting so you can start again. Yes I have gone to the support, hopefully they see common sense. Cheers